# Racket Macro, Print list of variable names and their values

Tags: macros, racket

I've got this macro:

```
(define-syntax inspect
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ x) (printf "~a is: ~a\n" 'x x)]))
```

Which works like so:

```
(let ([x 2]) (inspect x))
>> x is: 2
```

But what I'd like to do is extend it so that I have

```
(_ x ...)
```

and loop through the various values providing, printing out their variable names and values accordingly.

ie

```
  (let ([x 2] [y 3]) (inspect x y))
    >> x is: 2
    y is: 3
```

I'm a bit stuck on this part.

For example, with something like this:

```
(define-syntax (inspect stx)
  (datum->syntax
   stx
   (for ([i (cdr (syntax->list stx))])
     (printf "~a is: ~a" (syntax->datum i) i))))
```

I'm unsure how to get at the value of i, on the last line.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need to have a two-pattern rule -- you can do the whole thing with a `begin`:

```
(define-syntax-rule (inspect x ...)
  (begin (printf "~a is: ~a\n" 'x x) ...))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution:

```
(define-syntax inspect
  (syntax-rules ()
    [(_ x) (printf "~a is: ~a\n" 'x x)]
    [(_ x y ...) (begin (inspect x) (inspect y ...))]))
```

Note that the ordering of clauses is important.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm also trying to understand more about what's available to me in terms of the pattern variables.  I'll add an edit to the bottom of the question so you can see what I mean.